# EmberJS - {{moment-format 'date' 'output' 'input'}} repeats todays date in every row when used in {{#each} block

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I am using [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) addon in order to format the dates in the following table:

```
<tbody> 
  {{#each model as |model|}}
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <td>{{model.id}}</td>
      <td>{{model.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{model.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{model.date_of_birth}}</td>
      <td>{{model.inserted_at}}</td>
      <td>{{model.departed_at}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

`date_of_birth` property returned from the DB ha the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+|-hhmm
```

When I try to format it like below;

```
{{moment-format 'model.date_of_birth' 'DD/MM/YYYY' 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+|-hhmm' }}
```

I end up with a populated table full of unique rows, except the date of birth is just today's date on every single row.

I know I am missing something obvious and someone out there is going to make me look very silly!

Comment: try `{{moment-format model.date_of_birth 'DD/MM/YYYY' }}`

Comment: You are a wonderful human being, thank you very much!

Comment: great to hear that it has worked. I have posted it as an answer. Please accept the answer and anyone can see it in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass binding date object to the helper instead of passing its name as a string. Therefore use it like this:

```
{{moment-format model.date_of_birth 'DD/MM/YYYY' }}
```